# Facebook App review for Page Public Content Access

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, service, review

In order to provide the screencast for the App review I'd have to pull the data from a public page, of course which isn't possible as I don't have access to it (because my app hasn't been reviewed). Infinite loop forming...

So in order to provide the screencast I should use "dummy" data that I can pull from my own page for example? Or are the App reviewers expecting something different?

Comment: I am also looking for the same thing. Please let me know If you come across any solution. Thanks.

Comment: you can use your own page for testing, and for getting data. why not just try?